# Integrating around the upper half of $|z|=R$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

In a textbook it says that you can show that $ \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x^{2})+\sin(x^{2})-1}{x^{2}} \ dx = 0$ by considering $ \displaystyle f(z) = \frac{e^{iz^{2}}-1}{z^{2}}$ and integrating around a contour that consists of the real axis and the upper half of the circle $|z|=R$.

But that seems absurd since $e^{iz^{2}}$ grows exponentially along $|z|=R$ in the second quadrant as $R \to \infty$.

Comment: but the numerator of the integrand is $0$

Comment: @Leox It's $\cos (x^2) + \sin (x^2)$, not $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x$.

Comment: It seems to me that integration around the first quadrant only makes much more sense.

Comment: Oh, sorry :)...

Comment: Note that, the integrand is an even function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is a bit more involved than it appears.  You need to integrate two separate sections of the circle, using complex conjugates.  Consider first the integral

$$\oint_C dz \frac{e^{i z^2}-1}{z^2}$$

where $C$ is a $45-$degree wedge in the first quadrant, of radius $R$.  Then the contour integral is

$$\int_0^R dx \frac{e^{i x^2}-1}{x^2} + i R \int_0^{\pi/4} d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{e^{i R^2 e^{i 2 \phi}}-1}{R^2 e^{i 2 \phi}}+ e^{i \pi/4} \int_R^0 dt \, \frac{e^{-t^2}-1}{e^{i \pi/2} t^2}$$

As $R \to \infty$, the second integral vanishes.  (Why?)  By Cauchy's theorem, the contour integral is zero.  Thus,

$$\int_0^{\infty}dx \frac{e^{i x^2}-1}{x^2} = -e^{-i \pi/4} \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{1-e^{-x^2}}{x^2}$$

---

Now consider

$$\oint_C dz \frac{e^{-i z^2}-1}{z^2}$$

where $C$ is a $45-$degree wedge in the second quadrant, of radius $R$.  Then the contour integral is

$$e^{i \pi}\int_R^0 dx \frac{e^{-i x^2}-1}{x^2}+ e^{i 3 \pi/4} \int_0^R dt \, \frac{e^{-t^2}-1}{e^{i 3\pi/2} t^2} - i R \int_{\pi}^{3\pi/4} d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{e^{-i R^2 e^{i 2 \phi}}-1}{R^2 e^{i 2 \phi}}$$

Take $R \to \infty$ again and find that

$$\int_0^{\infty}dx \frac{e^{-i x^2}-1}{x^2} = e^{-i 3 \pi/4} \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{1-e^{-x^2}}{x^2}$$

---

The final thing to note is

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\cos{(x^2)}+\sin{(x^2)}-1}{x^2} &= \frac1{\sqrt{2}} \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-i \pi/4} (e^{i x^2}-1) + e^{i \pi/4} (e^{-i x^2}-1)}{x^2}\\ &= -\frac1{\sqrt{2}} e^{-i \pi/2} \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{1-e^{-x^2}}{x^2}+\frac1{\sqrt{2}} e^{- i \pi/2} \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{1-e^{-x^2}}{x^2}\\ &= 0\end{align}$$

Therefore, as the integrand is even,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{\cos{(x^2)}+\sin{(x^2)}-1}{x^2} = 0$$

as asserted.

Comment: In the textbook they literally argue that $ \displaystyle \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{C_{R}} |\frac{e^{iz^{2}}-1}{z^{2}}| \ dz =0 $ where $C_{R}$ is the upper half of $|z|=R$.  But they seemed to have used Jordan's inequality incorrectly.

Comment: @FractionalDerivative: yeah, that argument only works in the wedges I described.  As you observed, the integrand blows up in between.

Comment: Just for clarification, you're not saying that $ \displaystyle \frac{e^{iz^{2}}-1}{z^{2}}$ blows up on $|z|=R$ when $\pi/4 \le \phi \le \pi/2$, and $\displaystyle \frac{e^{-iz^{2}}-1}{z^{2}}$ blows up on $|z|=R$ when $\pi/2 \le \phi \le 3 \pi /4$, are you?

Comment: @FractionalDerivative: right; no they do not.  They blow up on their complementary pieces, if you know what I mean.